# Enabling bash-completion disables the default behaviour of auto-completing filenames

Tags: bash, makefile, bash-completion

My `make` version on macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6 looks like this:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

My Bash version looks like this:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

My current directory looks like this:

```
$ ls -1
Makefile
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

My `Makefile` looks like this:

```
hello:
        echo hello

%.txt: FORCE
        cat "$@"

FORCE:
```

#### Case 1: Without `bash-completion`

When I do not have `bash-completion` installed, I can conveniently autocomplete filenames in the current directory as the target argument for `make`. I mean, if I type:

```
make a<TAB>
```

it would automatically complete to:

```
make a.txt
```

#### Case 2: With `bash-completion`

When I do have `bash-completion` (such as with `brew install bash-completion`), I can no longer use this behaviour.

If I type:

```
make a<TAB>
```

it does not autocomplete at all. It does autocomplete other targets now such as `make he<TAB>` and `make FO<TAB>` which was not possible earlier but I lose the autocomplete any arbitrary filenames.

#### Question

- Why does installing `bash-completion` disable the default behaviour of autocompleting current filenames? I think that's a very convenient behaviour to have.
- How can I get that behaviour back without removing `bash-completion`. If I can do this, I can have the best of both worlds. Use auto-completions provided by `bash-completion` as well as auto-complete filenames in the current directory.

Comment: I can't reproduce this based on what you said. Maybe you also did something custom to enable make target completion?

Comment: @AlexHarvey Which part are you unable to reproduce? What environment are you in? If you are on macOS, then you need to `brew uninstall bash-completion; brew install bash-completion` and then follow the steps printed under `Caveats` in the brew output. That or you can just `source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` to enable the bash completion environment. If you are on a modern Linux like Ubuntu, this stuff should be enabled for you by default.

Comment: ok I got it, @lonelearner. See my answer below. :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, I think most people would not want Bash to offer files in the working directory as suggested targets for make.

But you can customise the behaviour without too much trouble.

Some useful docs on Bash Tab Completion can be found [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html).

It looks like the source code for the Bash Completion used on Mac OS X is [here](https://github.com/brechtm/bash-completion/blob/6e08dc550474c66bc09a539d7f35d2f58891be9c/completions/make#L60-L63). The line you care about is this one:

```
COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( make -qp $makef $makef_dir 2>/dev/null | \
    awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ \
    {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' )" \
    -- "$cur" ) )
```

You can see that the `compgen` builtin there generates the list of possible completions, based on the output of `make -qp Makefile .`.

You can hack this to work the way you want it to this way. First, copy the make-specific autocomplete file to your user bash completion file:

```
cp /usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_3/etc/bash_completion.d/make ~/.bash_completion
```

Then edit that file to specify a slightly different behaviour. Here, I'll show the diff:

```
--- /usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_3/etc/bash_completion.d/make  2019-02-06 18:35:00.000000000 +1100
+++ /Users/alexharvey/.bash_completion  2019-02-06 18:34:36.000000000 +1100
@@ -62,7 +62,7 @@

         COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( make -qp $makef $makef_dir 2>/dev/null | \
             awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ \
-            {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' )" \
+            {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' ; ls * )" \
             -- "$cur" ) )

     fi
```

Notice all I did there was to append the output of `ls *` to the response returned to `compgen` so that it considers files in the working directory to be also possible tab completions.

And that's it. Start a new shell.